# How to code in React the after() Jquery function?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and I want to manipulate the DOM similar to JQuery. For example, after clicking a `tr` element from a `Table`, I want to add another `tr` element after it. If I were using JQuery, I will call the "after" function (`$(element).after(element to add)`) to insert a new `tr` element after the element is selected. Is there any "after" function in React that allows me to do something similar or how can I approach it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to compare them because one is imperative and one is declarative. Fundamentally they are different concepts

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to React and I want to manipulate the DOM similar to JQuery.

Don't do that. React assumes that it's the only piece of code manipulating the DOM (at least, the section of the DOM you asked it to manipulate). If you make changes that it doesn't know about, it's very easy to cause bugs.

Instead, use the standard react mechanism for updating the page: state. You'll have some piece of state driving your component, and when you want to make a change, you update the state. In your case, you're probably going to have an array, and to add a new row, you add to the array. Something like this:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(['foo', 'bar']);

  return (
    <table>
      {data.map((value, i) => (
        <tr onClick={() => {
          setData(prev => {
            const next = [...prev];
            next.splice(i, 0, 'new row');
            return next;
          });
        })>
          <td>Row {i + 1}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </table>
  );
}
```